# How to enable compiz in VMWare Fusion

Tags: compiz, vmware

I am using Macbook Pro with OS Lion. I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my VMWare Fusion 4.1.0. I am wondering is there any way to activate the compiz / 3d.

I am new here and I really want to use Ubuntu 11.10 with my Mac OS X Lion VMWare Fusion.

Answer (score 1):

3D acceleration is possible since a few days. The [xf86-video-vmware driver](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-announce/2012-March/001873.html) was announced at the beginning of March 2012. It needs a specific kernel module which is available since Linux 3.2. If you try Ubuntu 12.04 LTS all of those software will be available to you. The site [vmware3d](http://www.x.org/wiki/vmware/vmware3D) in the [X.org wiki](http://www.x.org/wiki) has some more information.